# Форма HTML и JS

Tags: javascript, html

Пользователю нужно ввести один из кодов, которые записаны в массиве var `accept`
Если код из переменной совпадает, пользователя перекидывает на другой сайт, если неверный - вылезает `alert("Код неверный")`

```js
var accept = [
  1234,
  6523,
  4578,
  4562
];

function submit() {
  "use strict";
  alert("Success(no)");
  if (input === accept) {
    alert("Вы вошли");
  } else {
    alert("Код неверный");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <legend>Код</legend>
  <a>Извините, но для доступа к сайту нужно ввести код</a>
  <br><input type="text" placeholder="Код">
  <br><input type="submit" value="Проверить" class="inp" onClick="submit()">
</form>
```

Comment: `if (accept.indexOf(input) > -1) ...`. Но тут еще следует позаботиться, чтобы элементы `accept` и `input` были одного типа. Либо `Number`, либо `String`

Comment: ForestDumb, имейте в виду что Джаваскрипты видно всем желающим, поэтому такая "авторизация" пользователей не имеет смысла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так...

```js
var accept = [
  1234,
  6523,
  4578,
  4562
];

function onSubmit(form) {
  if (accept.indexOf(+form.code.value) > -1) {
    alert("Вы вошли");
  form.submit();
  } else {
    alert("Код неверный");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <legend>Код</legend>
    <a>Извините, но для доступа к сайту нужно ввести код</a>
    <br><input type="text" name="code" placeholder="Код">
    <br><input type="button" value="Проверить" class="inp" onclick="onSubmit(this.form)">
</form>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Если не трудно, проставьте комментарии, пожалуйста

Comment: Ввод `0x4d2` тоже позволяет войти. :)